# SEO Friendly URLs Rewrite Using Htaccess And Mod_Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I have used below RewriteRule in .htacces file then it is working as /page/NDT:REBGEARPOSGM-8630342

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9\-:]+$)$ page.php?partid=$1
</IfModule>
```

But I want work as /page/NDT:REBGEARPOSGM-8630342.html. For this I have used below RewriteRule and it is giving error 404 .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9\-:]+$)\.html page.php?partid=$1
</IfModule>
```

Any one please assist where I did wrong or any other way to do this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misplaced `$` anchor in your regex. Use this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options -MultiViews    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9:-]+)\.html$ page.php?partid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you very mych Anubhava. I wasted 3 hours for this and u saved my time.

Comment: Now I want "NDT:REBGEARPOSGM-8630342.html" instead of "/page/NDT:REBGEARPOSGM-8630342.html". What changes I need to do. I tried as per my knowledge but no luck. Can u please assist Anubhava.

Comment: I tried with removing pages but not working.
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9:-]+)\.html$ page.php?partid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

Comment: Actually `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9:-]+)\.html$ page.php?partid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` is correct and worked for me.

Comment: Here it is not allowing (:, -) symbols. without these it is working.